# Unable to load the GADM data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have downloaded the shapefile of Mexico's Admin Boundaries from the [GADM](http://www.gadm.org/country) site but I am not able to load it in QGIS.

It keeps giving me the following error,

> /Users/smaranh/Downloads/MEX_adm/MEX_adm2.prj is not a valid or
>   recognized data source

But I simply downloaded the shapefile and loading it in the QGIS, then why is there a problem with the projection?

Can somebody guide me pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the *.shp file, not the *.prj file.

Comment: I am new to qgis and so thought like Arcmap I need to drag all the file into the map window. Simply dragged and dropped the .shp and it is working. Thanks